# "Log in to Community as User" Button Missing

Tags: community, customer-community, button, login

I know that in the Winter release the "Log in to Community as User" button was added to Lightning. I did look at other pre-existing topics for this subject and none of those answers resolved the issue for me.

I am a System Admin and I have access to the button when viewing a Contact. 
Our core users do not, however (but they do in Classic, so I know they have permissions).

Things I checked based on other topics:

- They have "Manage External Users" permissions.
- They have Read/Edit on Accounts.
- Their Role is in the same Sharing Groups that my role is in.
- The buttons are being displayed on all of our page layouts for the Contact object.

Comment: Does Sys Admin and other Users have the same layout?

Comment: @JayantDas We have different layouts, but each Page Layout has the button being displayed in the "Contact Detail" --> "Standard Buttons" section.

Comment: Can you verify for the impacted page layout, if the button is available on the page layout in the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Action"?

Comment: *edit*
That worked! 
I was trying to add the "Button" to that section, not the "Mobile & Lightning Actions". Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Winter '18, Users can manage Community Users in Lightning Experience. Snippet from the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm):

> No more switching between Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic to manage external community members. From within Lightning Experience, you can create and disable partner and customer accounts and users and log in as a community user.
>
> Good news! All actions that you can take on a person account in
>   Salesforce Classic are available in Lightning Experience.
>
> And the fun doesn’t stop there. All login actions that are available
>   in Salesforce Classic can also be performed in Lightning Experience.

In the issue mentioned here, Users had different page layout that as of Admin, and Admins were able to view the button in LEX. For any button to be visible in LEX, it needs to be available in **Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Action** section of the page layout. Adding it in there will make any buttons available in page layouts in LEX (refer screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Jayant Das pointed out that the "Log in to Community as User" button needed to be added to the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" section. I had been looking at the "Contact Details" --> "Standard Buttons" area.

By clicking on "Mobile & Lightning Actions" area in the top-left while editing the Page Layout (NOT "Buttons"), and dragging it to the "Salesfroce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" area, this made the link appear for the users.

Thanks again Jayant Das!

Comment: Great! Glad that it worked, happy to help. I added in some more details as an answer for anyone who has similar issue.